# Codeigniter : won't work pagination with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-pagination

I have this function in Controller that call all item from model and make pagination in home page, So i call home page like :

```
http://localhost/cart/index.php/
```

When go to next page show me this error :

```
404 Page Not Found
```

My controller :-

```
public function index() {
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->main_model->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 8;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $data["home_products"] = $this->main_model->fetch_items($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['categories'] = $this->main_model->getAllCategories();

    $this->load->view("home", $data);
}
```

and the model :

```
    public function record_count() {
            return $this->db->count_all("wg_items");
    }

    public function fetch_items($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get("wg_items");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
   }
```

and view :

```
        <!-- Show pagination links -->
        <p style="float:left"><?php echo $links; ?></p>
```

Where is error ??

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
$count = $this->main_model->record_count();

$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url() .'index.php/Front/index';
$config["total_rows"] = $count ;
$config["per_page"] = 8;
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
$limit = $config['per_page'];

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

$data['home_products'] = $this->main_model->get_item($page,$limit);
```

in model

```
public function get_item($page,$limit)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table name  LIMIT $page, $limit");//your argument
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

in `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in `.htaccess`(Place outside of applicatino folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thankx, but is show me error
`<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/details/<?php echo $product->item_id; ?>/<?php echo strtolower(url_title($product->item_name)); ?>"><span class="dummy"></span></a>`
Message:  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: can you upload full code. il make it correct. post view, model and controller.

Comment: how you get product?? passing any `id` through url??

Comment: controller
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lc5ukn9sc00jsd4/front.php?dl=0
view
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hix4yd9czxv05u7/home.php?dl=0
model 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ef1y88ddp720po8/main_model.php?dl=0

Comment: how you pass id yo controller??

Comment: in home page no pass any id , its get all item

Comment: so how you cal the function with product id??

Comment: i call function ( index ) to get all item in table so no need to any id